# Denoting higher-order tensors with a rectangle under a letter

Tags: tensor

I denote higher-order tensors using a capital letter and a rectangle under it. It basically looks like:

[image]

And well, after one hour on the Internet, I simply cannot find how to do it in LaTeX. Can someone show me how to do it please ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks for the welcome :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers ! I'll take the time to try out the different solutions before marking one as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Set to work in all math styles.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\hot[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \sbox0{\kern-.5pt$\SavedStyle#1$\kern-.5pt}%
  \stackengine{.2\LMex}{\kern.5pt\copy0\kern.5pt}{%
    \rlap{\rule[-.5\LMex]{.4\LMpt}{.5\LMex}}%
    \rlap{\rule[-.5\LMex]{\wd0}{.4\LMpt}}%
    \rule{\wd0}{.4\LMpt}\llap{\rule[-.5\LMex]{.4\LMpt}{.5\LMex}}%
  }{U}{c}{F}{F}{S}
}}
\begin{document}
$\hot{A}= 3\hot{z}$

$\scriptstyle\hot{A}= 3\hot{z}$

$\scriptscriptstyle\hot{A}= 3\hot{z}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wanted it automatically in upright style, then the instance of `#1` in the definition of `\hot` could simply be adjusted to `\mathrm{#1}`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my take: the thickness of the box rules varies according to the current math style, as well as the height. Both depend on the current style's fraction line thickness, that is, `\fontdimen8 <font>3`.

If you're using `lmodern`, remember to load also `fixcmex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rtens}[1]{%
  \mathpalette\rtens@{\mathsf{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\rtens@}[2]{%
  \vtop{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1#2$}% measure the width
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \usebox{\z@}\cr
      \noalign{\nointerlineskip\vskip2\rtens@thickness{#1}}
      \rtens@rect{#1}\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\rtens@rect}[1]{%
  \fboxrule=\rtens@thickness{#1}%
  \fboxsep=-\fboxrule
  \fbox{%
    \rule{0pt}{4\rtens@thickness{#1}}% height
    \kern\wd\z@\kern-\rtens@thickness{#1}% width
  }%
}

\newcommand{\rtens@thickness}[1]{%
  \fontdimen 8
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont3\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont3\else
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont3\else
  \scriptscriptfont3
  \fi\fi\fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\rtens{A}$ $\rtens{g}$

$\scriptstyle\rtens{A}$ $\scriptscriptstyle\rtens{g}$

$\rtens{A}\scriptstyle\rtens{A}$

\Large $\rtens{I}\rtens{J}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I never I have seen to denote higher-order tensors with a rectangle under a letter. What is this book? Boh :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano Never did I too!

Comment: Hello @Sebastiano !
This notation is, from what I know, far from being standard. It is a generalization of the notation where one underline denotes a vector, two underlines denote a matrix, and so on. Because writing too many underlines can be a pain, replacing them with something else for higher-order tensors seems necessary; one could use a thicker line, but it would be a pain to write with a pen. Hence the rectangle, which is essentially a hollow version of the thick line :) But yeah, it is far from being standard. I'm just too used to it to use something else

Comment: @Kal8578 Underline and double underline for vectors and matrices is very old-fashioned.

Comment: @Kal8578 Very kind user. My was just a curiosity considering that I use the indices for the tensor or a notation of a capital letter with an hat using \leftrightarrow. Actually it is common to use the indices for a tensor, but never I have seen this symbol. Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\underbox}[1]{%
 \stackunder[1.5pt]{#1}{\fboxsep0pt\fbox{\rule{6pt}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{1.5pt}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\underbox{A}

\underbox{$A$}

\end{document}
```

[image]